# Add EC22 security rule via AWS PHP SDK2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

The script is allocating an IP but I'm not seeing the security rule in the GUI. No errors are being thrown. Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
$config = aws_setup();
$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);
$gmodel = $ec2Client->allocateAddress();
$args = array('GroupName' => 'www', 'IpPermissions' => array(array('IpProtocol' => 'tcp', 'FromPort' => 22, 'ToPort' => 22)), 'IpRanges' => array('CidrIp' => array($gmodel->get('PublicIp') . '/32')));
$ec2Client->authorizeSecurityGroupIngress($args);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the right syntax for the 'args' variable:

```
$args = array('GroupName' => 'www', 'IpPermissions' => array(array('IpProtocol' => 'tcp', 'FromPort' => 22, 'ToPort' => 22, 'IpRanges' => array(array('CidrIp' => $gmodel->get('PublicIp') . '/32')))));
```

The rule is now being added to the security group.